# Generate the same "random" values each test run in Autofixture

Tags: autofixture

I would like to create (complex) types with random values using Autofixture. I do not care about the value of created data as long as all values are different. I would like to have [Autofixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture) create the same data each test run.

By default data with Autofixture can lead to flaky tests where a test sometimes passes and sometimes fails.

To make it a little more clear. This is an example of the behaviour I am looking for. This should also work for complex types, but I didn't implemented that in the example.

```
[Fact]
public void AlwaysTheSameValues()
{
    var semiRandomValues = new SemiRandomValues();
    int value1 = semiRandomValues.GetRandomInt(); // Always 145
    int value2 = semiRandomValues.GetRandomInt(); // Always 163
    int value3 = semiRandomValues.GetRandomInt(); // Always 153

    string value4 = semiRandomValues.GetRandomString(); // Always "NFNWLYGHLPLYAVYQHUVY"
    string value5 = semiRandomValues.GetRandomString(); // Always "ARNXRNCELHYQTAJIXMRC"

    Assert.True(value2>50); // This wil never fail
}

[Fact]
public void DifferentValuesEachRun()
{
    var semiRandomValues = new Fixture();
    int value1 = semiRandomValues.Create<int>(); // Produces a different result in each run
    int value2 = semiRandomValues.Create<int>(); // Produces a different result in each run
    int value3 = semiRandomValues.Create<int>(); // Produces a different result in each run

    string value4 = semiRandomValues.Create<string>(); // Produces a different result in each run
    string value5 = semiRandomValues.Create<string>(); // Produces a different result in each run

    Assert.True(value2 > 50); // This wil sometimes fail
}
```

using this class

```
public class SemiRandomValues
{
    private readonly Random _random = new Random(0); // The 0 makes all value the same each run

    public int GetRandomInt()
    {
        return _random.Next(1, 200);
    }

    public string GetRandomString()
    {
        var chars = Enumerable
            .Range(1, 20)
            .Select(_ => (char)_random.Next(65, 90))
            .ToArray();
        return new string(chars);
    }
}
```

Note: I don't want to depend on a random value (on purpose) but with the default Autofixture behavior I can (accidentally) check in a working unit test that is not failing. After that when a colleague is running that test later, it can fail. For that colleague it is also hard to reproduce the failing test as the test can be successful later.

Answer (score 0):

I made an example illustrating a couple of approaches.
One method is to use DataAnnotations, and the other is to create customizations that make sure you get default values that make sense in your case.

Mark Seeman [wrote about this over a decade ago](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/10/19/Convention-basedCustomizationswithAutoFixture/).

```cs
void Main()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new MySpecimenBuilder().ToCustomization());
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        var foo = fixture.Create<Foo>();
        Console.WriteLine($"{i} Bar: {foo.Bar}, Baz: {foo.Baz}, Qux: {foo.Qux}");
        // Example output
        //0 Bar: 42, Baz: ABCDE983, Qux: 42
        //1 Bar: 42, Baz: ABCDE821, Qux: 42
        //2 Bar: 42, Baz: ABCDE974, Qux: 42
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Bar { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"ABCDE\d{3}")]
    public string Baz { get; set; }

    [Range(42, 42)]
    public int Qux { get; set; }
}

public class MySpecimenBuilder : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        return request switch
        {
            PropertyInfo pi when pi.Name == nameof(Foo.Bar) => 42,
            _ => new NoSpecimen()
        };
    }
}
```